# How to programatically respond to Python libraries that request input from stdin?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using a library that has a call that asks for user input via stdin. I'm attempting to use the library via an API and won't be using it via the console. Is there a way to provide the values that it wants via code?

This is an example flow that I'm trying to *avoid*.

```
import hello_world

hello_world.login()

# Please provide your login username:

# STDIN: testuser

hello_world.is_authenticated # true
```

I'd like to be able to do this all via the script. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the library is written in Python, you can for example `@patch` `__builtin__.raw_input`. You can also connect whatever you want to your own process’s stdin using normal Unix means of doing so (that’s what you’d do to implement a shell!). On Windows you can do something similar using the native console redirection.